# How can I compile Ruby to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, compiler-construction, opalrb

I'm working on a piece of logic that I would like to express on the server as well as in the browser. Something like validating a form where there must be certain logical relationships between the elements based on what has already been entered.

So... If I can write the logic once and somehow end up with both Ruby and with Javascript, I can write the logic just once and not have to worry about making sure that two pieces of code written in different languages have the same functional behaviour.

I don't need to reproduce everything in Ruby, obviously, and one simplification might be to port a single general-purpose library like [Functional Javascript](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/) to Ruby.

Does anyone have experience with RubyJS? Can anyone point me to an existing project using RubyJS? 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 18):

As far as I can tell, [Opal](http://opalrb.com/) is the best Ruby to JS converter/compiler out there right now. [Here](http://opalrb.com/try/#code:class%20Person%0A%20%20attr_accessor%20%3Afirst%2C%20%3Alast%2C%20%3Agender%0A%20%20def%20initialize(first_name%2C%20last_name%2C%20g)%0A%20%20%20%20%40first%20%3D%20first_name%0A%20%20%20%20%40last%20%3D%20last_name%0A%20%20%20%20raise%20%22Nope%22%20if%20(g%20!%3D%20%3Am%20%26%26%20g%20!%3D%20%3Af)%0A%20%20%20%20%40gender%20%3D%20g%0A%20%20end%0A%20%20def%20parent_type%0A%20%20%20%20if%20gender%20%3D%3D%20%3Am%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22father%22%0A%20%20%20%20elsif%20gender%20%3D%3D%20%3Af%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22mother%22%0A%20%20%20%20end%0A%20%20end%0A%20%20def%20full_name%0A%20%20%20%20%22%23%7Bfirst%7D%20%23%7Blast%7D%22%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0Ame%20%3D%20Person.new(%22Bob%22%2C%20%22Smith%22%2C%20%3Am)%0Ap1%20%3D%20Person.new(%22John%22%2C%20%22Smith%22%2C%20%3Am)%0Ap2%20%3D%20Person.new(%22Sue%22%2C%20%22Smith%22%2C%20%3Af)%0A%0Aputs%20%22My%20name%20is%20%23%7Bme.full_name%7D!%22%0A%0Aputs%20%22My%20%23%7Bp1.parent_type%7D%20is%20%23%7Bp1.first%7D!%22%0Aputs%20%22My%20%23%7Bp2.parent_type%7D%20is%20%23%7Bp2.first%7D!%22) you can see it in action.

It isn't perfect, but it works most of the time and unlike older projects such as [RubyJS](https://github.com/superchris/rubyjs), Opal is still being actively developed.

Answer (score 6):

I know about http://hotruby.yukoba.jp/ but have never used it

Comment: This is very definitely a different approach to solving the problem. Very interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

maybe this helps:
http://opalrb.org/
haven't tried it though

Answer (score 1):

I recently heard about a project named "Johnson" which embeds the Spidermonkey JavaScript interpreter inside Ruby.  http://github.com/jbarnette/johnson

You could then eval some javascript inside ruby.

Comment: As cool as this is, it doesn't answer the OP's question at all.