# Production usage of compiling Ruby Red to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, compiler-construction, production-environment, opalrb

There has been a lot of discussion over this ability (such as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144169/how-can-i-compile-ruby-to-javascript), or [this github thread](http://github.com/jcoglan/js.class/issues#issue/1)) to compile ruby to Javascript. The original version of [Red](http://github.com/jessesielaff/red) is quite old, but Julius Eckert seems to have [picked it up](http://github.com/julius/red) and made it far more usable (and even [presented it](http://www.julius-eckert.com/2009/06/02/ruby-red/))

After seeing the community backing up compiling other languages, such as [Coffescript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/), to javascript I wonder: has anyone use the latest Red in production? How was the experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of response is response enough. Sadly.

Answer (score 2):

Now's the time to check out Opal:

- http://opalrb.org
- https://github.com/opal/opal
- http://opal.github.io/opal-playground/rspec/

;)